# How to install the development version of lme4 in osx

Tags: r

There are currently issues with the standard installation for the development versions of lme4. How can I get the current development version (0.99999911.0 or higher) to work in OSX ?

The command suggested in http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org

doesn't seem to work:

```
install.packages("lme4",repos="http://r-forge.r-project.org")
```

Comment: Actually,I don't want "lme4.0" but if I use : install.packages("lme4",repos="http://r-forge.r-project.org") this fails...

Comment: at present, the best way to get the *development* version of `lme4` is: `install.packages("devtools"); library("devtools"); install_github("lme4",user="lme4")`

Comment: Thank you sir! I'm trying to get influence.ME to work with lme4 but having issues with that as well. Seems a patch to influence.ME is required.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the answer is to install via github, using the `devtools` package.

```
library("devtools")
install_github("lme4",user="lme4")
```

For this to work, the latest version of Xcode including command line tools is required.